# What is the recommended way to log regularization losses for TensorBoard 2.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I want to be able to monitor the evolution of the regularization losses of my model with TensorBoard (I'm using TensorFlow 2.1).

Until now, I've set up a [`tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard) callback passed to [`tf.keras.Model.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). It allows me to monitor the total loss and the learning rate:

[image]

The callback logs them by default.

However the total loss is composed of multiple terms (e.g. regularization losses). How can I easily monitor them?

1. The [`tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/TensorBoard) doesn't seem to support this. Right?
2. I found this doc section: [Logging custom scalars](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/scalars_and_keras#logging_custom_scalars). However the example shows how to monitor a scalar at *each epoch end* while I'm looking for something which collect scalars at *each batch end* and log the mean at *each epoch end*.
3. I guess I can write a custom callback but can I avoid spending time on this?
4. Is there another solution?

Hence my question, what is the recommended way to log regularization losses for TensorBoard 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own callback by inheriting from the `TensorBoard` callback and manually adding the desired quantities.

Here is the code I am using for that purpose. In this case, you would get a separate graph for the regularization losses of each layer.

```py
class CustomTBCallback(keras.callbacks.TensorBoard):
    def _log_metrics(self, logs, prefix, step):
        for layer in self.model.layers:
            if layer.losses:
                logs["reg_%s" % layer.name] = tf.reduce_sum(layer.losses)
        super()._log_metrics(logs, prefix, step)
```

Unfortunately, this is somewhat hacky as it relies on the private `_log_metrics` function which may change between different versions of tensorflow. I have used this with tf 2.0.